# How to delete on upper level directory from the package name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, directory, package

I know How to rename the package name in Android studio. I have done this every time and its easy to do in android studio . but Now I am stuck in a condition which is as below

**My package name**

> com.example.andygreson.talkmania

**where as I want it to be**

> com.andygreson.talkmania

**I want to delete the example directory from the package name**. But when Ever I do , **it deletes all the project inside it**.

Please tell me how to do this

Comment: Take a backup of your project.Go to File explorer.cut the `talkmania` folder and paste it under `andygreson` and refresh the project.Resolve the errors.

Comment: you create as new package name according to want and then copy and pest all class file in your new package. and change in menfesto file in package name. its work.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: I was searching the direct way of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AndroidStudio ,

Take backup of your `com.example.andygreson.talkmania` package 
then
Create new package you want `com.andygreson.talkmania`  now copy all files from last package and paste into this one.

dont forget to change in **AndroidManifest** file

Refresh studio. its done.